# Safe conversion to const char * - temporary lifetime problem

Tags: c++, casting, temporary

I have a following template defined so that I can perform an explicit, but safe cast:

```
/// cast using implicit conversions only
template <class To,class From>
inline To safe_cast( const From &from ) {return from;}
```

Frequently (e.g. when passing arguments into sprintf and similar functions) I would like to use this template to perform a conversion from a string class to a c-style string. However, it shows this is not possible when temporary is passed, because the temporary will not live long enough.

Consider following example:

```
class Object
{
  public:
  MyStringClass GetDebugName() const;
};

Object obj;
printf("%s",safe_cast<const char *>(obj.GetDebugName()));
```

The temporary from obj.GetDebugName() lives only during the safe_cast and the pointer is invalid (points to the data of the string temporary which has already been destroyed) when inside of the printf.

As a workaround I a currently using direct cast without a template call: `const char *c = (const char *)(obj.GetDebugName()`, but this has a drawback of reduced type safety, as the cast is unnecessarily strong (e.g. it would silently succeed even if obj.GetDebugName() would be returning int instead of a string value). `static_cast` might be slightly better, but even that is too strong, I would like to get an error on any situation where cast is not sure to be safe.

1) If I am not mistaken, the standard says the temporary life time is a statement (unless extended by being bound to a const reference, in which case it is the life time of the reference). When looking at the printf example above, I am not quite sure what a "statement" is, and if the behaviour I have seen is conformant or not. If the statement is the whole printf, the lifetime of the const From &from is shorter - what lifetime should I expect from the temporary? Can someone clarify?

2) Is there some other way to make a conversion which would be safe, but the result would live long enough to be useful?

Edit:

Please, consider this more a kind of general question, I am seeking for a mechanism how can a conversion like this to be done with regard to the temporary lifetime, I am not that much interested in a special case of any particular string class.

To clarify why I do not want to use .c_str or a similar member function: I would like the conversion code to be type agnostic, I do not want the code to rely on the fact I know this particular string type has c_str implemented, I want it to work even if a different string class would be returned by ObjectDebugName, or even if ObjectDebugName would be already returning const char * (which excludes the possibility of calling .operator const char *().

Comment: How do you do const char *c = (const char *)(obj.GetDebugName()). Is there some "operator char*" inside of MyStringClass ?

Comment: I may be mistaken, but wouldn't temporaries created in an expression live until the end of the whole expression (end of call to printf)?

Comment: Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214153/lifetime-of-temporaries/4214179#4214179) about lifetime of temporaries.

Comment: @visitor: They do. But temporaries created in the statement `return from;` live until the end of *that* statement.

Comment: Voting to close. The question was asked because of a bug experienced with previous version of Visual Studio and is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can perform an explicit, but safe cast

I would call it an implicit cast done explicitly, or just and explicit implicit cast.

> 1) If I am not mistaken, the standard says the temporary life time is a statement (unless extended by being bound to a const reference, in which case it is the life time of the reference). When looking at the printf example above, I am not quite sure what a "statement" is, and if the behaviour I have seen is conformant or not. If the statement is the whole printf, the lifetime of the const From &from is shorter - what lifetime should I expect from the temporary? Can someone clarify?

You are correct, the temporary is destroyed **after** printf've returned.
The code you provided should work. If it doesn't, it means that you misprovided some important information.

Comment: I will check again if the safe_cast and temporary lifetime is still causing a problem. I browsed my archives now and it shows the problems with temporary lifetime were seen in year 2004, i.e. before Visual Studio 2005.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you are using your own string class here. Does the class have a member function to get the const char * out of it?

std::string GetDebugName();

printf( "%s", GetDebugName().c_str() );

would be safe as the temporary would remain valid during that statement, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the conversion function directly:

```
printf("%s", obj.GetDebugName().operator const char*());
```

Comment: That might also look as `static_cast<const char*>(obj.GetDebugName())`, which leads to the question: why is the `safe_cast` function needed at all?

Comment: @UncleBens: The proposed `safe_cast<To>(From const&)` template will also consider `To::To(From const&)`. The direct call I wrote is only subject to const-volatile overloading which is generally harmless.