# When is an anonymous C++ object destroyed?

Tags: c++, variables, scope

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Lifetime of temporaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214153/lifetime-of-temporaries)

I'm assuming `std::string::c_str()` returns a pointer to some internal (to `std::string`) data. Pretend this is true if it's not. In the following, `name` is set is to point to this internal data. When is the `std::string` returned by `GetString()` destroyed, causing name to be invalid?

```
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

string GetString() {return string("TheString");}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    const char* name = GetString().c_str();
    printf("name = %s\n",name);
}
// Should print "name = TheString"
```

Comment: Great example of different wordings for asking the same question.

Comment: I hate when people upvote duplicates ::sigh::

Comment: @Brian: Don't worry, be happy. =)