# Lifetime of return value in comma separated statements

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, comma-operator

Is the order of execution of the three commented lines below guaranteed?

```
struct S
{
    S() { /* called 1st */ }
    ~S() { /* called 3rd */ }
};

boost::shared_ptr<S> f() 
{
    return boost::shared_ptr<S>(new S); 
}

int second() { return 0; /* called 2nd */ }

int test()
{
    return (f(), second());
}
```

With my compiler, the `shared_ptr` returned by `f()` seems to persist until after `second()` is called.  But is this guaranteed by the standard and thus other compilers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lifetime of temporaries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214153/lifetime-of-temporaries)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes**.

Temporaries persist until the completion of the `full-expression`.

> `[n3290: 12.2/3]:` When an implementation introduces a temporary
>   object of a class that has a non-trivial constructor (12.1,
>   12.8), it shall ensure that a constructor is called for the temporary object. Similarly, the destructor shall be called for a temporary with
>   a non-trivial destructor (12.4). Temporary objects are destroyed as
>   the last step in evaluating the full-expression (1.9) that (lexically)
>   contains the point where they were created. This is true even if that
>   evaluation ends in throwing an exception. **The value computations and
>   side effects of destroying a temporary object are associated only with
>   the full-expression, not with any specific subexpression.**

And:

> `[n3290: 1.9/10]:` **A full-expression is an expression that is not a
>   subexpression of another expression.** If a language construct is
>   defined to produce an implicit call of a function, a use of the
>   language construct is considered to be an expression for the purposes
>   of this definition. A call to a destructor generated at the end of the
>   lifetime of an object other than a temporary object is an implicit
>   full-expression. Conversions applied to the result of an expression in
>   order to satisfy the requirements of the language construct in which
>   the expression appears are also considered to be part of the
>   full-expression. [..]

This means that both `f()` and `second()` should exist until execution returns from `test()` with the result of evaluating the latter.