# Reference to temporary, which was created by a type operator

Tags: c++, temporary, lifetime

Let's assume that we need some class for wrapping std::string, and besides all other details, it provides an automatic conversion back to std::string, using a type cast operator:

```
class MyWrappedString {
    std::string m_value;
    /* ... */
public:
    inline operator std::string() const {
        return m_value;
    }
};
```

So, the operator **will return a copy** of the wrapped string object.

But, why is the following code seemingly correct?

```
MyWrappedString x;
const std::string& y = x;
// now, y should be a reference to a temporary, right?
std::cout << "y is: " << y << std::endl;
```

The conversion operator will return a temporary copy of m_value, so `const std::string& y = x` will create a reference to that temporary copy.

Why does this work? I remember there was some kind of extension of lifetime of referenced objects, but I am not sure.

And second question: is it possible to have a type cast operator that returns a const reference?

E.g.:

```
inline operator const std::string &() const {
    return m_value;
}
```

So, that the above code does not have to work on a temporary copy?

PS: This question is a bit related to: [Lifetime of temporaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214153/lifetime-of-temporaries), but still a different issue.

Comment: If you have two separate questions, make two separate posts.

Comment: Herb Sutter on the question relating to lifetimes of const references to temporaries: http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: yes, but it would be hard to explain the context of it two times. So, someone answering question 1 can likely answer question 2 too :)

Comment: I don't see why your second question could not be true. Your conversion operators can return whatever you want, including const references. They're just another member function.

Comment: @Alex: thx, this answers my first question

Comment: The first is ok as long as you have the const on the receiving end. The second doesn't make a copy or temporary and is a const reference to the member. Both are valid for the lifetime of `x` in your case I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const` references are keeping the reference alive (even if it would have gone out out of scope normally) until the const reference goes out of scope

For the second question: yes, you can return a const reference, and the return value from the function will have to be assinged to a const reference

Comment: okay. `operator const std::string &() const` works (in VS2010 and gcc4). I did not expect that, but it just works. Though, one can not have both (with & without reference). Thx!

Comment: @Frunsi: I believe in not having implicit type conversions... but if you are going to offer them, it is better in your case to provide the `const std::string&`, as that lets the caller decide whether they want to copy the string or not.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: yes, right, I don't believe in implicit type conversions either. But here in my special use case, it is just very convenient. However, I am still extremely surprised, that a type cast operator returning a const reference just works. I am sure, any compiler has a hard time supporting these (because references are not just types, but have special meaning, like its extended lifetimes and so on...)

Comment: @Frunsi: reference **are** types. There are some extra rules (namely lifetime extension through binding to a `const&`), but they are as much of a type as pointers...