# What's the scope of this string?

Tags: c++, c++builder, c++builder-xe

If I have the following code:

```
{
    UnicodeString sFish = L"FISH";
    char *szFish = AnsiString(sFish).c_str();

    CallFunc(szFish);
}
```

Then what is the scope of the temporary `AnsiString` that's created, and for how long is `szFish` pointing to valid data? Will it still be valid for the `CallFunc` function?

Will it's scope last just the one line, or for the whole block?

Comment: Not familiar with `UnicodeString` or `AnsiString`, but the string must last at least until the block ends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C++11 standard $12.2.3 says:

> When an implementation introduces a temporary object of a class that
>   has a non-trivial constructor (12.1, 12.8), it shall ensure that a
>   constructor is called for the temporary object. Similarly, the
>   destructor shall be called for a temporary with a non-trivial
>   destructor (12.4). **Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in
>   evaluating the full-expression (1.9) that (lexically) contains the
>   point where they were created.** This is true even if that evaluation
>   ends in throwing an exception. The value computations and side effects
>   of destroying a temporary object are associated only with the
>   full-expression, not with any specific subexpression.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

There are additional caveats to this, but they don't apply in this situation. In your case the full expression is the indicated part of this statement:

```
char *szFish = AnsiString(sFish).c_str();
//             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

So, the instant `szFish` is assigned, the destructor of your temporary object (i.e. `AnsiString(sFish)`) will be called and its internal memory representation (where `c_str()` points to) will be released. Thus, `szFish` will be immediately become a dangling pointer and any access will fail.

You can get around this by saying

```
CallFunc(AnsiString(sFish).c_str());
```

instead, as here, the temporary will be destroyed (again) after the *full* expression (that is, right at the `;`) and `CallFunc` will be able to read the raw string.

Answer (score 5):

`szFish` is invalid before the call to `CallFunc()`, because `AnsiString` is a temporary object that is destructed immediately and `szFish` is pointing to its internal buffer which will have just been deleted.

Ensure that the `AnsiString` instance is valid for the invocation of `CallFunc()`. For example:

```
CallFunc(AnsiString(sFish).c_str());
```

Answer (score 4):

I would replace:

```
char *szFish = AnsiString(sFish).c_str();
```

with:

```
AnsiString as(sFish);
char *szFish = as.c_str();
```

I don't know the `AnsiString` class but in your code its destructor will fire before your call to `CallFunc()`, and will most probably release the string you point to with `*szFish`. When you replace the temporary object with a "named" object on stack its lifetime will extend until the end of the block it is defined in.

Comment: yeah, I've fixed it that way. I wanted to be 100% sure about why.

Comment: Here is a good explanation (taken from C++ standard, I believe) of lifetime of a temporary object http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214153/lifetime-of-temporaries $12.2/3- "Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression (1.9) that (lexically) contains the point where they were created. This is true even if that evaluation ends in throwing an exception."

Answer (score 1):

The scope of the `AnsiString` in this case is "from right before the call to `c_str()`, until right after."

It may help to think of it this way:

```
char *szFish; 

{ 
    AnsiString tmpString(sFish); 
    szFish = tmpString.c_str(); 
}
```