# C++ Error reading character of String using Strtok

Tags: c++, strtok

The problem here resides with reading the `char * nv`, which basically points to `0xCCCCCCCC` with the error `Error reading characters of string`

Already tried other fixes. There are more steps to this code but this is the simplified, overly-specific version:

```
char** splitStr(char* str, char separator, int sizeRet) {
    char ** tot = new char *[sizeRet];
    char * sep = new char[2];
    sep[0] = separator;
    sep[1] = '\0';
    char * nv;
    nv = strtok(str, sep);
    int i = 0;
    while (nv != NULL) {
        tot[i] = nv;
        nv = strtok(NULL, sep);
        i++;
    }
    return tot;
}
```

Update

The code works in an online compiler perfectly. It doesn't work in Visual Studio 2017 for some odd reason. Will try eliminating some folders from the framework I have to use, and try again.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't do `char sep[2];` instead of allocating on the heap? (plus you're leaking since you've forgotten to delete it)

Comment: Why oh why would you do this: `char * sep = new char[2];`? Of course the obvious has happened: you forgot to delete it and have a memory leak. You might need to show how you call `splitStr()`.

Comment: You should never use strtok in C++, or in C, really.

Comment: I had to create the auxiliar sep[2] to create a constant char for strtok, which is, on itself, a terrible function

Comment: John, I had to create it to "convert" the char separator to a constant char, in order to use it inside the strtok. I certainly forgot to delete it, but does it really affect the execution of the next sequence of code?

Comment: `const char sep[] = { separator, '\0' };`

Comment: What problem are you having with the code? The only issue I can see is that there's no way to tell where the last token is in the returned array.

Comment: You allocate `sizeRet` elements for `tot`, but nothing in your loop restricts it to accessing only `sizeRet` elements. You might have a buffer overrun.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik We could say that's the caller's problem, they should ensure that `sizeRet` is large enough (e.g. at least `strlen(str)`)

Comment: @Barmar We could say that, yes. But perhaps the problem the OP is having is precisely that the caller (conspicuously absent from the question) failed to ensure that.

Comment: `Error reading characters of string` doesn't sound like a standard error, where does that come from?

Comment: perhaps the `Error reading characters of string` is related to the used IDE ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18946459/error-reading-characters-of-string

Comment: i am running the code in question on an onlice c++ compiler, and am only getting seg faults at the first strtok. No mention of `Error reading characters of string`

Comment: Using Visual Studio, the problem was not with the Separator, and sizeRet is in fact large enough according to the rest of the code which is specific to calculating it. The problem is specifically when reading the string to which I apply strtok; oddly enough, If I decide to allocate memory for it, it only returns garbage. It's weird

Comment: This function works for me if `str` is a real character array (`char str[] = "a string";`), but it segfaults if I pass a string literal as `str`.  This is because `strtok` [writes to the string each time it finds a token](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok).

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem is solved. Decided to stop usign strtok and doind the good old iterative runs avoiding the separators and Voila, it works perfectly. I hate Visual Studio though