# warning: ‘<anonymous>’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]

Tags: c++

The following program compiles without warnings with `-O0`:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
  int const& x_;
  inline operator bool() const { return true; }
  Foo(int const& x):x_{x} { }
  Foo(Foo const&) = delete;
  Foo& operator=(Foo const&) = delete;
};

int main()
{
  if (Foo const& foo = Foo(3))
    std::cout << foo.x_ << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

However with `-O1` or higher it gives the warning:

```
maybe-uninitialized.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
maybe-uninitialized.cpp:15:22: warning: ‘<anonymous>’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
 std::cout << foo.x_ << std::endl;
```

How do you get rid of this warning with `-O1` and higher?

The motivation for this is for a `CHECK(x)` macro which must capture a const reference rather than a value so as not to trigger a destructor, copy constructor, etc. as well as print out a value.

*Resolution is at the bottom*

*Edit:*

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 8.2.1 20181127

No warnings:  g++ maybe-uninitialized.cpp -Wall -O0
With warning: g++ maybe-uninitialized.cpp -Wall -O1
```

*Edit 2 in response to @Brian*

```
#include <iostream>

struct CheckEq
{
  int const& x_;
  int const& y_;
  bool const result_;
  inline operator bool() const { return !result_; }
  CheckEq(int const& x, int const &y):x_{x},y_{y},result_{x_ == y_} { }
  CheckEq(CheckEq const&) = delete;
  CheckEq& operator=(CheckEq const&) = delete;
};

#define CHECK_EQ(x, y) if (CheckEq const& check_eq = CheckEq(x,y)) \
  std::cout << #x << " != " << #y \
    << " (" << check_eq.x_ << " != " << check_eq.y_ << ") "

int main()
{
  CHECK_EQ(3,4) << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

The above is more interesting in that there are no warnings, but different output depending on the `-O0` or `-O1`:

```
g++ maybe-uninitialized.cpp -O0 ; ./a.out
Output: 3 != 4 (3 != 4) 

g++ maybe-uninitialized.cpp -O1 ; ./a.out
Output: 3 != 4 (0 != 0)
```

#### Edit 3 - Accepted answer

Thanks to @RyanHaining.

```
#include <iostream>

struct CheckEq
{
  int const& x_;
  int const& y_;
  explicit operator bool() const { return !(x_ == y_); }
};

int f() {
  std::cout << "f() called." << std::endl;
  return 3;
}

int g() {
  std::cout << "g() called." << std::endl;
  return 4;
}

#define CHECK_EQ(x, y) if (CheckEq const& check_eq = CheckEq{(x),(y)}) \
  std::cout << #x << " != " << #y \
    << " (" << check_eq.x_ << " != " << check_eq.y_ << ") "

int main() {
  CHECK_EQ(f(),g()) << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
f() called.
g() called.
f() != g() (3 != 4)
```

Features:

- Each parameter to `CHECK_EQ` is only checked once.
- Output displays inline code comparison as well as values.

Comment: Cannot reproduce - please provide the full commandline you used.

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: I'm surprised you didn't get a warning from the non-optimized build.  `Foo(3)` is never right because class member references will not extend the life of a temporary.  Can you show what you are actually trying to acomplish with your macro and we should be able to help with that.  I'll try and see if there is a dupe target for this.

Comment: You could replace your macro with `auto CHECK_EQ = [](auto&& x, auto&& y) -> decltype(auto) { if (x != y) return std::cout << x << " != " << y  << " (" << x << " != " << y << ") "; else return (std::cout); };` and get the same results without any UB, copying, or moving

Comment: @NathanOliver Nice idea I will try that.

Comment: @NathanOliver that is (somewhat surprisingly) not true for aggregates, see answer below

Comment: @RyanHaining Very nice.  I was not aware aggregates behaved that way.  TIL :) (+1 on the answer btw)

Comment: I forget to say, having `inline` is unnecessary for a definition a member function in a class body, the `operator bool` here is implicitly `inline`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While a class with a user-defined constructor cannot extend the lifetime of the temporary, [an aggregate can](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23965233/1013719). By converting to an aggregate I can make your approach work

```
#include <iostream>

struct CheckEq
{
  int const& x_;
  int const& y_;
  bool const result_;
  explicit operator bool() const { return !result_; }
};

// adding () here for macro safety
#define CHECK_EQ(x, y) if (CheckEq const& check_eq = CheckEq{(x),(y),((x)==(y))}) \
  std::cout << #x << " != " << #y \
    << " (" << check_eq.x_ << " != " << check_eq.y_ << ") "

int main() {
  CHECK_EQ(3,4) << '\n';
}
```

This produces the same output with and without -O3 for me

Comment: Made a slight change so that each parameter is evaluated only once. Thanks again for the great answer.

Comment: Fyi `CHECK_EQ(3,std::min(4,5))` gives the warning with `-Wall -O3` but `CHECK_EQ(3,std::min(4,5)+0)` does not. Presumably this is due to `std::min` returning a `int const&` to its own parameter which doesn't survive when passed to `CheckEq`.

Answer (score 4):

The code has undefined behaviour. Calling `Foo`'s constructor causes the materialization of the prvalue `3` as a temporary object, which is bound to the parameter `x`. But the lifetime of that temporary object ends when the constructor exits, leaving `x_` as a dangling reference by the time `foo.x_` is evaluated.

You need to give more details about how you want your `CHECK` macro to work before it's possible to suggest a way to implement it without doing what you're doing here.

Comment: Has it though? I don't see Foo cause materialization of anything but aliasing. I'm tired....

Comment: I think you are on to something. I added an example with `CHECK_EQ` and now different output is produced depending on the optimization level. If you are able to suggest a way so that the `-O0` behavior is achieved with the `-O3` flag I would appreciate it, but you have already addressed the original question so I'll accept your answer if there are no better ones.