# Is it safe to call non-const member functions for rvalue objects?

Tags: c++, c++11

While reading about multithreading in C++11, I noticed that some tutorials do this:

```cpp
std::thread(print_message, "Hello").detach();

// instead of...

std::thread t(print_message, "Hello");
t.detach();
```

My questions are:

1. In general, is it safe to call non-const member functions for temporary (rvalue) objects?
2. In particular, is it safe to do so for a C++11 `std::thread`?

Comment: For point 1: it's safe to call member functions that don't have a precondition (for class types etc in namespace std).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Yes: the non-const function gets executed while the object is still alive, so there is no problem.
2. Yes: `std::thread` behaves as any other type.

Comment: We should also mention that when calling `detach`, the parent thread usually doesn't care about keeping a reference to the child. When calling `join`, however, it should.

Answer (score 6):

To elaborate more on the second question, the temporary `std::thread` object behaves like any other temporary object:

It is destroyed after the [full expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4214153/1012936) it is bound to is evaluated, which means [the destructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread) is always called after the `.detach()` call - `std::terminate()` is not called.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to question 1:
You are not allowed to modify anonymous temporaries of "non-class" type (i.e.. built-in types). You are, however, allowed to call non-const member functions on anonymous temporaries of "class" type.
See Section 3.10.10 in C++ ISO/IEC 14882:1998 standard.